# Android Outlook

Tags: android, outlook

I want to ask how to open the outlook in the android device. how can i send the mail with the android outlook. i want to create the android application in which user select the email address after selecting the E-Mail address android outlook will open in the device after that he write the message in the message body. and after clicking on the send option mail will send to the user.

Comment: Thaper: "Outlook" is a Windows application. "Android" is a non-Windows operating system. There is no "outlook in the android device".

Comment: then how can i send the mail with this. May i create the layout for this or android contain any class that works like outlook

Answer (score 0):

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {}); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "HomeworkNowSubject");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HomeworkNowBody");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));

but please ensure that it will perform only "onclicklistener" event not on "onCreate"